# fetching data from firebase fine but not rendering when i reload app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore

when add this code, the app runs as suposed to, but when i reload the app, it stops rendering as it should and give me a full blanck page

```
  </div>
      <div className="chat__body">
        {messages.map((message) => (
          <p className={`chat__message ${true && "chat__reciever"}`}>
            <span className="chat__name">{message.name}</span>
            {message.message}
            <span className="chat__timestamp">
              {new Date(message.timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}
            </span>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
```

whith this message error when inspecting Uncaught TypeError: messages.map is not a function

do someone know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: None of the code you shared calls loads data from Firebase, so it's hard to say where it's going wrong. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this   `const [messages, setMessages] = useState("");` and if i change that to `const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);`  it works

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough code but I'm guessing you're probably not accounting for the loading time of your Firebase data. `messages.map` is the culprit, you're trying to loop over messages but they're initially empty until Firebase has a chance to send you back the data.

You would need to check if the data is loaded before accessing it. A quick example in pseudo-code would be:

```js
const [isLoading, set_isLoading] = true;

getFirebaseData().then(() => set_isLoading(false))

if(isLoading) return "Loading...";

return <div>{messages.map( ... )}</div>
```

But I would recommend using a firebase library that can provide this type of functionality for you.

Another workaround is also to use optional chaining to have safer code:
`messages?.map` instead of `messages.map`.